# Module not found error in python for networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to deploy a python web project on flask with the following code snippets:

```
import sys, numpy as np
import logging
import networkx as nx
import common as cm
```

I have also used pip install networkx to install the libraries:

```
pip install networkx
```

It is still giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\User\Documents\ppi-research\main.py", line 3, in 
import contacts as ct
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\ppi-research\contacts.py", line 3, in 
import networkx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'

Comment: what python version? are you running in a virtual environment?  or using an integrated IDE like Spyder? many possible issues ..

Comment: Yes, I am using a virtual environment with a flask. The python version is 3.9.5

Comment: are you sure the virtual environment has been activated before running the script? also, can you run `python -m pip list` and confirm `networkx` is in the output?

Comment: Yes. Here is the path-------(venv) C:\Users\User\Documents\ppi-research>

Comment: Also the result of the command---Package      Version
------------ -------
click        8.0.1
colorama     0.4.4
decorator    5.0.9
Flask        2.0.1
itsdangerous 2.0.1
Jinja2       3.0.1
MarkupSafe   2.0.1
network      0.1
networkx     2.2
numpy        1.21.1
pip          21.1.1
setuptools   56.0.0
Werkzeug     2.0.1

Comment: seems you have a good setup. I don't know what might be the problem, but I would suggest re-creating a new virtual-environment, install only `networkx` and start with one script with one line `import networkx` and see if that fails. If it  works then move your project to the new virtual-environment. If it fails, then at least you have isolated the problem, and might need to re-install python or some other fundamental software.

Answer (score 0):

do `pipenv install networkx` while in a virtual env (pipenv shell).